# Why did my cursor change to a circle?

Tags: select

My cursor switched to a circle and I don’t know how to switch it back. Now I can’t select any objects except for where the orange dot is located. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, I believe you mistakenly pressed the C key, which is used to select vertex or deselect them. To remove the circle cursor just press right click on your mouse or return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>W</kbd> to alternate between selection types.

Comment: Pressing `W` activates the selection tool and toggles selection mode after it is active, not types of cursors. Could you clarify that in your answer

Answer (score 5):

Or maybe Circle Tool has been permanently activated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To deactivate the selecting tool, right click on your mouse or press Return or ESC.

Comment: This will not work if the _Select_ tool was accidentally switched to _Select Circle_ by pressing `W`, which is most likely the case here. Pressing `W` multiple times will go through all different _Select_ modes, but after the default _Select Box_, the _Select Circle_ tool is the first to come up when you press `W` just once.